# How to combine the elements of two list

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have two list

```
List1 = ['foo', 'bar', '.txt']
List2 = [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

I want the output to be

```
output = ['foo1bar3.txt', 'foo1bar4.txt', 'foo1bar5.txt', 'foo2bar3.txt', 'foo2bar4.txt', 'foo2bar5.txt']
```

Comment: Use list comprehensions ( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions ) and zip ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip )

Comment: `zip` is actually pointles here.

Comment: @schwobaseggl but `itertools.zip_longest` is not :D

Comment: @timgeb hmm.. the only way I could use any zipping here would be to cycle through an iterable producing List1 over and over again. But then, I could use a plain `zip`.

Comment: `[str(List1[0]) + ''.join(f'{y}{x}' for x, y in zip(List1[1:], l2)) for l2 in List2]` or `[''.join(f'{x}{y or ""}' for x, y in itertools.zip_longest(List1, l2)) for l2 in List2]`

Comment: @Drecker Oh, zip at the inner level.. ok. Looks heavily overengineered :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl `[''.join(chain(*zip_longest(List1, map(str, t), fillvalue=''))) for t in List2]` unreadable but does the job. Or `c=cycle(List1); [f"{next(c)}{i}{next(c)}{j}{next(c)}" for i, j in List2]` ;)

Comment: @timgeb I like the last one:  `[f"{a}{i}{b}{j}{c}" for a, b, c, (i,j) in zip(c, c, c, List2)]` for readability :D

Comment: @schwobaseggl not enough itertools porn but I take it.

Comment: Same amount as your last one, just omitted the cycle line

Comment: oh, right, that's why zip_longest+chain is better

Comment: If you don't have to stare down your own code 5 minutes later, you're not doing it right :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
a, b, c = List1
output = [f"{a}{x}{b}{y}{c}" for x, y in List2]
# ['foo1bar3.txt', 'foo1bar4.txt', 'foo1bar5.txt', 'foo2bar3.txt', 'foo2bar4.txt', 'foo2bar5.txt']
```

Comment: It gave me an error- ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: Thank you so much. Yea it is perfectly working now.

Comment: You people with your fancy modern string formatting... overlooking what would've been obvious to you five years ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ['foo', 'bar', '.txt']
list2 = [(1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
list3 = []

for x, y in list2:

    list3.append(list1[0] + str(x) + list1[1] + str(y) + list1[2])

print(list3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['foo1bar3.txt', 'foo1bar4.txt', 'foo1bar5.txt', 'foo2bar3.txt', 'foo2bar4.txt', 'foo2bar5.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

One that doesn't hardcode the number of elements:

```
output = ['%d'.join(List1) % x for x in List2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCoQwDEX3PUU2khaKYJ2B2XgDbyAuHAaZzqIpNYKevppON3nwfpIfT/5S6F8x5Tz6jTsYYMKVCC3ge0mClg/GWUnsJNadhd5YED4qn0JXvaveiZ@Vop3jzuVz88H2Rz7oUmaggQNWSvf0AUrDvR@TD6z/VybnCw)

Comment: thank you. can you please explain what the '%d' and % is doing?

Comment: @ramit Just formatting the number tuples into the joined string. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting